# Paginate Comments With will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I'm using the `will_paginate` gem and currently have a list that is already paginated.

`@businesses = Business.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7)`

`<%= will_paginate @businesses %>`

`<% @businesses.each do |business| %>`

To display the comments for a particular entry I use:

`<% @business.comments.each do |comment| %>`

I thought something like the following might work but it didn't:

`@business.comments = Business.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7)`

`<%= will_paginate @business.comments %>`

I can't seem to find any answer to paginating the comments (99.9% sure its to do with it being @something.something instead of just @something)

Comment: Are you sure you're using `Business.comments.paginate` rather than `@business.comments.paginate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `@business.comments` not only won't work but is actually dangerous and destructive. You are setting the comments associated to the business to be **only** the ones returned by that paginate call. (Check what the log shows when you set `@business.comments` to the paginated call.

You have, however, got the call right. You just need to set it to a different variable rather than reusing `@business.comments`. If you use @comments instead it will work fine:

```
@comments = @business.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7)
```

and

```
@comments.each do |comment|
  ...
end
will_paginate @comments
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error but if i change the per_page limit to "1" it still shows all three comments (but with 3 pages available in the number bar 1,2,3)

Comment: Did you change your loop code to `@comments.each do |comment|`? I've edited to include that change too.

Comment: Yes but that produces an error "The @businesses variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?".. why have you changed `@business.comment.each do` to `@comments.each do`This code has come from the RoR.org tutorial `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model`

Comment: We're not touching `@businesses` with the changes we've made to paginate `@comments`. That suggests you have changes something unrelated to comments or haven't changed the `will_paginate` call to `will_paginate(@comments)`. I have changed `@business.comments` to `@comments` so that you can paginate them which is not covered in the tutorial.

Comment: I didn't mean my question to sound like I was complaining, just wasn't sure what the change did. I had a spelling error that was stopping the changes from working - Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem at all. Just trying to clarify - glad you got it working.