# I'm paginating comments with AJAX but it's loading duplicates, not new pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to load comments by paginating them on a blog post via AJAX and the `will_paginate` gem.

The problem I'm facing is that it's not segmenting the total amount of comments for that post to different pages, it is simply loading duplicate comments of the initial render or "first page of comments".

**application.js:**

```
// LOAD MORE POSTS (BLOG INDEX)
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($('#paginate-load-more-button').size() > 0) {
    $('#paginate-load-more-button .pagination').hide()

    $('#load-more-posts').show().click(function() {
      more_posts_url = $('#paginate-load-more-button .pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $this = $(this);
      $this.html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" title=" Loading..." /> ').addClass('disabled');
      $.getScript(more_posts_url, function() {
        if ($this) {
          $this.text('Load more posts').removeClass('disabled');
        }
      });
    });
  };
});
```

**Posts > show.js.erb:**

```
$('#listing-load-more-button').append("<%= j render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @post.comments) %>");
<% if @comments.next_page %>
  $('#paginate-load-more-button .pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @comments %>');
  $('#paginate-load-more-button .pagination').hide();
<% else %>
  $('#paginate-load-more-button .pagination, #load-more-posts').remove();
<% end %>
```

*The partial `'comments/comment'` that is being rendered, is simply each individual comment entry with a reply form.*

**Posts > show.html.erb:**

```
<div id="listing-load-more-button">
  <%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @post.comments) %>
</div>

<div id="paginate-load-more-button">
  <%= will_paginate @comments %>
</div>

<% if @comments.next_page %>
  <div class="center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="load-more-posts" class="btn btn-info top-drop">Load Comments</a></div>
<% end %>
```

**PostsController:**

```
def show

  ...

  @comments = Comment.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3).order('created_at DESC')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

I've also tried using `@comments = @post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3).order('created_at DESC')` instead as I learned from [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765016/7372897) but it still doesn't seem to work properly.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: when and how are you doing the ajax request?

Comment: @arieljuod on-click, by using the last `if` statement in my posts show.html.erb.

Comment: You've got `a href="javascript:void(0);"` so I guess you have some javascript to do the actual ajax request that's not on the question.

Comment: @arieljuod Thank you for pointing this out! I forgot I used JS for triggering this, I was thinking it was just being used to nullify a link. I updated my question with it.

Comment: Check the server log if the request comes with the right `page` param. Then, use the browser dev tools, add a breakpoint inside the js functions, and check if `more_posts_url` has the correct url with the correct `page` parameter. Your code seems to be right though.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you are rendering `collection: @post.comments`, you should render `collection: @comments`.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks! It works when it's changed to that in both the js.erb and the html.erb but only when I use the alternative `@comments` value that I tried using - mentioned below my original one. Leave an answer to this and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering `collection: @post.comments` (that's not the paginated relation), you should render `collection: @comments`.